# How to use IMediaObject?

Tags: directshow, directshow.net, dmo

I just want to query the number of streams in a file. But an unimaginable difficulty has emerged from this simple task.

It seems the query involves using IMediaObject.I have searched IMediaObject documentation in DirectShow. It only lists out its functions but it has no samples and description on how to use it.

I have also searched Windows 7 SDK. The only demonstration is in **dmoenum**
The initiation is incapsulated in ShowSelectedDMOInfo(const GUID *pCLSID)

what types can pCLSID be? Any samples are out there to illustrate how to use IMediaObject?

Answer (score 1):

> I just want to query the number of streams in a file

`IMediaObject` is not of any help. It only returns number of streams it is designed to accept on the input and deliver on the output, according to its design. Typical DMO has one input and one output stream, completely irrelevant to file streams.

In DirectShow you can query streams from demultiplexing filter for the respective file format. These are rarely (if ever) packaged as DMOs.

Comment: should I use MPEG-2 Demultiplexer? MSDN documentation is really unsupporting. I don't know COM very well. Moreover, there aren't any samples or good guides there. I am really perplexed

Comment: You should use it for what exactly purpose?

Comment: i want to extract subtitles from teletext wtv files. I think the first thing I need to do is to read the stream?

Comment: It will take time to attempt to mount random things and eventually get it working. [Consumption of a WTV file in DirectShow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc963726.aspx) looks like a starting point. If you figure out how basic consumption works, you will be able to start fitting it to your needs.

Comment: I have read this. but I still don't know how to output any reading from this code...
and there is no executive. I don't know how this program behave

Comment: besides, I use directshowsharp. There is no corresponding FindOutputPinByType method.

Comment: This make it harder, but since you are on the path of using DirectShow through wrapper library, you have to deal with more complicated code porting.

Comment: here is a line "spGraph->AddSourceFilter(sSourceFileName, L"Source Filter", &spSBE);" 
what kind of strings I should put here for "Source Filter"?

Comment: [See MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd390087%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), this string is informational, any will do.

Comment: I just read it. I don't understand its meaning.
I have seen most samples provide null for the parameter or use the file name. 
so this parameter has no practical function but it's only for a appearance/naming purpose?